# How gsub works in ruby with meta characters in input

Tags: ruby

I need help in understanding how the following works.

```
"middl'-.*$%ddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiExcess".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z'-.]/, '')
# => "middl'-.*ddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiExcess"

"middl'-.*$%ddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiExcess".gsub(/[^a-zA-Z.'-]/, '')
# => "middl'-.ddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiExcess"
```

When I give `/[^a-zA-Z'-.]/`, then the star is not removed, but in the second example, the star is removed. Why?

I want the result after `gsub` to have only letters (`a-zA-Z`), period (`.`), hypen (`-`), single apostphe (`'`) to exist. Just by changing the period position inside regular expression the output is different ?

Comment: Maybe this might help you : https://bneijt.nl/pr/ruby-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/[^a-zA-Z'-.]/` hyphen is treated as range delimiter, exactly as in `A-Z` before. The range is:

```
▶ ("'"..'.').to_a
#⇒ ["'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", "."] # note asterisk
```

In `/[^a-zA-Z.'-]/` hyphen is the last symbol and hence it is treated as hyphen itself.